# Unable to cast object of type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

Tags: c#

I am trying to add drop down list to the excel. I am doing this for first time.

Can any body tell why i am getting the error?

Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

Following is code:

```
            var cell1 = (Range)workSheet.Cells[4,4];


            cell1.Validation.Delete();
            cell1.Validation.Add(
               XlDVType.xlValidateList,
               XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
               XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
               List,
               Type.Missing);

            cell1.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            cell1.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```